# How to resolve akka-http issues?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm new to Akka-Http. I added following Route

```
path(urlpath / "messages") {
    post {
        decodeRequest {
            withoutSizeLimit {
                entity(asSourceOf[Message]) { source =>
                    val storeToDb = Flow[Message].map[Future[Message]](message => (service ask message).mapTo[Message])
                    val sendToProviderFlow = Flow[Future[Message]].map[Unit](message => sendToJasminProvider(message))
                    val futureResponse = source
                                            .via(storeToDb)
                                            .via(sendToProviderFlow)
                                            .runWith(Sink.ignore).map(_ => "Message Received")

                    complete(futureResponse)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried run above Route, I've been receiving couple of errors and I do not know how to fix them.

Issues:

- Accept error: could not accept new connection java.io.IOException: Too many open files
- [1] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior,This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
- akka.http.scaladsl.model.EntityStreamException: Entity stream
  truncation

Answer (score 0):

About first error, it's seems that you open too many connection. Maybe you simply didn't close them somewhere. Unix used similar connection for sockets and files

About second error, it's obvious that your actor (service) is dead. Try to debug your actors lifecycle and start with

```
enabling akka.actor.debug.lifecycle = on
```

For more details visit this page
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/logging.html#auxiliary-logging-options

Is `sendToJasminProvider` has type `Future[Message] => Unit`? If that function has type like `Future[Message] => Future[T]` then it's problem